# android how to make a 2-dimensional array of icons

Tags: android, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a simple way to make a 2-dimensional array of icons for a board game on android. I wrote a game in java but it uses swing and I am now trying to rewrite it for android. I have searched all over and have found ways to make the 2-d array but I don't know how to fill it with icons now. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code from java using the swing lib.):

```
    spots = new JButton[15][15];
        grid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(15, 15));
        for (int i = 0; i < spots.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < spots.length; j++) {
                spots[i][j] = new JButton();                
                spots[i][j].setActionCommand(i + ":" + j);  
                spots[i][j].addActionListener(this);        
                grid.add(spots[i][j]);
                spots[i][j].setIcon(backgroundIcon);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You well need to create a `ImageView[][]` to hold your icons. And you can use the `GridView` to display them. It's a rather fixed-size problem so I would recommend using an `ImageView[]` or `List<ImageView>`. Have a look at this [sample](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html).

Note: you can set the `OnClickListener` of an ImageView.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I apologize that it took me so very long to respond, I couldn't remember any of my credentials for the account.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think you should use a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) and manage the spots (with a Custom [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html)) as a list rather than a 2d array. You could wrap functions around your list which could allow it to be treated as a 2D array. Otherwise you are going to have to deal with custom views and adapters from the beginning. Also trying to import too much code from a spring app could get messy

If you really want to use a 2D array you could create your layout with a group of [ImageViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) for each element in the array and use your xml styling attributes (`android:layout_below` `android:layout_toRightOf`) to create the board look.

You could then populate your 2d array with handles to these image views for example:

```
spots[0][0] = findViewById(R.id.coords_0_0);
```

Then you could call.

```
spots[0][0].setImageResource(R.image.newPiece);
```

When you want to change

Comment: Thanks, and I apologize to you as well. I updated my account credentials now so I will be able to get in again. Your answer was also quite helpful.

Comment: I will once I get two more reputation, unfortunately I just started actively using this site today so I don't have the privileges yet.